# Mesos kills container when requests increase

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, apache-mesos

I deploy Docker containers on Mesos(0.21) and Marathon(0.7.6) on Google Cloud Engine (Ubuntu 14.04).
I use JMeter to test a REST service that run on Marathon. When the concurrent requests are less than 10, it works normal, but when the concurrent requests are over 50, the container is killed and Mesos start another container. I increase RAM, CPU but it still happens.
This is log in /var/log/mesos/

```
E0116 09:33:31.554816 19298 slave.cpp:2344] Failed to update resources for container 10e47946-4c54-4d64-9276-0ce94af31d44 of executor dev_service.2e25332d-964f-11e4-9004-42010af05efe running task dev_service.2e25332d-964f-11e4-9004-42010af05efe on status update for terminal task, destroying container: Failed to determine cgroup for the 'cpu' subsystem: Failed to read /proc/612/cgroup: Failed to open file '/proc/612/cgroup': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you look at the docker container logs?

Comment: I had a similar problem when running different apps - when there was not enough ram and cpu and the process tried to allocate more resources, it was killed and restarted (thus cancelling all the active connections). It may be, that you have still not enough resources allocated for the container.

Comment: The [maximum number of connections](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) in a GCE VM is quite high (130k for small VMs). Therefore this parameter should not be an issue. I believe the right way to go,as previously mentioned,is to examine the container logs.Nevertheless a helpful tool to monitor the resources in your VM is [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent).Additionally checking dmesg could help to discard that the behavior is caused by lack of resources in your VM. I would also recommend trying [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post self-answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

refs: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1837

```
MESOS_isolation='cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem'
MESOS_cgroups_root='system.slice/mesos-slave.service'
MESOS_cgroups_hierarchy=/sys/fs/cgroup
```

it will resolve your question.